# Eigen values of A if principal minors are all positive .

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my book, there is a statement which says "If all the principal minors of A are positive , all the eigen values of A need not be positive ". Here A is a square matrix.

I think if principal minors are all positive then sum of eigen values which is the trace is positive, product of eigen values is positive and also A(i,i) which is element at ith row and ith column is also positive. So, how can any eigen value be negative ?

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric, or are there any other conditions on it?

Comment: No conditions. It was just given A. However, if answer varies based on conditions then I would like to know that too.

Comment: Then you can find $t$ for which $\begin{pmatrix} \cos{t} & -\sin{t} \\ \sin{t} & \cos{t} \end{pmatrix}$ has no real eigenvalues, but with $\cos{t}>0$, and the determinant is $1$.

Comment: What is true is that the real part of every eigenvalue is positive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if $\epsilon > 0$, $$A = \pmatrix{\epsilon & -1\cr 1 & \epsilon\cr}$$ has all its principal minors positive, but its eigenvalues are $\epsilon \pm i$ which are not real and therefore not positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Having all principal minors positive is the definition of a [P-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-matrix). Hence, while in general the eigenvalues are not positive, the do have localization away from the negative real axis. If $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then for $n > 1$ we have

$$|\arg{\lambda}| < \pi (1 - 1 / n).$$